# A query to get me specific alphabetic order

Tags: oracle

I have a table called `telephone_contacts` that contain two columns:

```
telephone_contacts (
  Name    varchar(100)
  Numbers number(20)
)
```

the column `name` contains about 20,000 rows.

I want to filter the name by alphabetic , example:

I want a query that get me only the first 6 alphabetic `(A , B, C , D ,E ,F G)`

Then, a query that get me the last 6 alphabetic `(U,V,W,X,Y,Z)`

Edit:

example: the column name contains the following data:
**Abe, car, night, range, chicken, zoo, whatsapp,facebook, viber Adu , aramt, Bike, Male, dog,egg**

I want a query that get me only `(A , B, C , D ,E ,F G)` so the results will be

abe ,care ,chicken facebook,adu,aramt,bike, dog, egg 
the rest are ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BETWEEN` if it is sequential.

**CHAR version**

```
SELECT * FROM telephone_contacts WHERE SUBSTR(UPPER(Name),1) BETWEEN 'A' and 'G'
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM telephone_contacts WHERE SUBSTR(UPPER(Name),1) BETWEEN 'U' and 'Z'
```

**ASCII Version**

```
SELECT * FROM telephone_contacts WHERE ASCII(SUBSTR(UPPER(Name),1)) BETWEEN 65 and 65+6-1
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM telephone_contacts WHERE ASCII(SUBSTR(UPPER(Name),1)) BETWEEN 90-6+1 and 90
```

***FOR testing:***

```
WITH my_view AS
  (SELECT chr(level+65-1) my_text FROM dual CONNECT BY level <=26
  )
SELECT * FROM my_view WHERE SUBSTR(UPPER(my_text),1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'G';
```

Comment: ah greate I like it , it will give me to F , it will not give to G

Comment: Btw can I use row num ? I mean If have I have 20,000 rows can I select only the first 10,000 row ?

Comment: can you give me how to do a query by row number ? but the problem If i choose the first 10,000 num how to do know the rest ? I want to divide the 20,000 row into 10,000 and 10,000 row

Comment: Sorted by Alphabetic.. for only the letters you look for? And BTW, you use PL/SQL or Java/PHP ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45297/discussion-between-maheswaran-ravisankar-and-moudiz)